# Circle velocities stay the same after elastic 2D collision

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, collision-resolution

I am following [this paper](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~rolf/Edu/DM815/E10/2dcollisions.pdf) in trying to create elastic 2D collisions among two circles. The problem is that my end velocities are the same as my start velocities. I've looked over my code and don't see anything off.

This is what I am hoping to achieve:

[image]

Maybe a second pair of eyes will notice something obviously wrong:

```
function resolveCircleCollision(playerOne, playerTwo) {
    // http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~rolf/Edu/DM815/E10/2dcollisions.pdf

    var xDiff = playerTwo.objectData.pos.x - playerOne.objectData.pos.x;
    var yDiff = playerTwo.objectData.pos.y - playerOne.objectData.pos.y;
    var normalVector = new Vector(xDiff, yDiff);

    if(normalVector.mag() <= playerOne.objectData.radius + playerTwo.objectData.radius) {
        // Normal/tangent unit vectors
        var normalUnitVector = normalVector.normalized();
        var tangentUnitVector = new Vector(-1 * normalUnitVector.y,     normalUnitVector.x);

        // Resolve velocity vectors into normal/tangential components
        var playerOneNormalComponent = normalUnitVector.dot(playerOne.velocity);
        var playerOneTangentComponent = tangentUnitVector.dot(playerOne.velocity); // Same post collision
        var playerTwoNormalComponent = normalUnitVector.dot(playerTwo.velocity);
        var playerTwoTangentComponent = tangentUnitVector.dot(playerTwo.velocity); // Same post collision

        // Find normal components post collision
        var playerOneNormalComponentPrime = (playerOneNormalComponent * (playerOne.mass - playerTwo.mass) + (2 * playerTwo.mass * playerTwoNormalComponent)) / (playerOne.mass + playerTwo.mass);
        var playerTwoNormalComponentPrime = (playerTwoNormalComponent * (playerTwo.mass - playerOne.mass) + (2 * playerOne.mass * playerOneNormalComponent)) / (playerOne.mass + playerTwo.mass);

        // Convert the components into vectors
        var playerOneNormalVector = normalUnitVector.multiply(playerOneNormalComponentPrime);
        var playerOneTangentVector = tangentUnitVector.multiply(playerOneTangentComponent);
        var playerTwoNormalVector = normalUnitVector.multiply(playerTwoNormalComponentPrime);
        var playerTwoTangentVector = tangentUnitVector.multiply(playerTwoTangentComponent);

       // Add the two components and set them equal to the player velocities
        playerOne.velocity = playerOneNormalVector.add(playerOneTangentVector);
        playerTwo.velocity = playerTwoNormalVector.add(playerTwoTangentVector);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean pre velocity of player one is equal to post velocity?

Comment: `playerOne.velocity` pre-collision == `playerOne.velocity` post-collision and `playerTwo.velocity` pre-collision == `playerTwo.velocity` post-collision

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Your code is working fine at least in unity

Comment: You can check [this](https://gyazo.com/9c26f20e2dc711858281fdcc773e58ac) first object has mass = 1 and second has mass = 0.5. pre velocity of obj1 = (0.3,0.0) and pre velocity of obj2 = (0,0) and post velocity obj1 = (0.1,-0.1) and post velocity of obj2 = (0.3,0.2)

Comment: I realized that yes, this code indeed does work. It was just that the velocity was not updating in my loop for whatever reason. I simply had to  update the position inside this function after calculating the velocity.

Comment: Mannn, you grabbed my day.. I did convert ti into c# :P But one thing, this all code was written in the gameloop.